# Send data from node.js to frontend using pure js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, dom

I am trying to send an object with data from a Node.js server to js file (for using this data in frontend).

In the file **main.js** I am manipulating the DOM. I do the following request:

```js
let dataName = [];
let request = async ('http://localhost:3000/') => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    dataName = data.name;
}

let name = document.getElementById('name');
name.textContent = dataName;
```

Then in the file **server.js** I have an object:

```js
data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Jhon"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Mike"
    }
];
```

And I would like to send it as json string (or another way) to **main.js** as response for my request.

**Problem:** My data is displayed on window in browser. How could I get it as response?

**I tried**

```js
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
app.use(express.static(`main`));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.json(data); //also tried to do it through .send, but there data only on window in browser
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Could someone tell me what to change in my code or point me in the direction in which to google? (I don't want to use template engines).

Help me pls :) Peace be with you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are trying to serve your frontend and the JSON data on the same URL `/`.

You need to adjust your server code as follows:

```js
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
app.use(express.static(`main`));
app.get('/api', function(req, res){
    res.json(data); //also tried to do it through .send, but there data only on window in browser
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Now your data will be available as JSON from `/api`. Then you can make a request on the frontend as follows:

```js
let dataName = [];
let request = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api');
    const data = await response.json();
    dataName = data.name;
}

let name = document.getElementById('name');
name.textContent = dataName;
```

There was also an issue with the `url` not being defined properly as an argument. I adjusted the function to simply use the URL string in the right place.

Comment: Thank you very much! I served server and index.html on the same URL :) Now I have another problem but I think I can fix it by myself. Also thank you for correcting my English(it is not my native:))).

Comment: @Alexx awesome! no worries, I corrected + added formatting so that it is easier to read in case someone has the same question and comes here from google later. welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a server that can communicate using **REST API**

*(Assuming data is a string)*

client:

```js
let data = getSomeDataYouWantToSend()
fetch('/send', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    },
    body: data
})
```

**Assuming you have static files in `/main` directory and html files in `/views` directory**

server:

```js
let express = require('express')
let app = express()

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/main`))
app.set('views', `${__dirname}/views`)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.html')
})

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body) // <- here is your data sent from client frontend
})

app.listen(3000)
```